# Query porformance vs performance of the same query in cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, cursor

I have a query, which uses subqueries and joins. I checked that query, it runs very well (fast). But then, I created cursor, where I placed exactle the same query, and then used that cursor in a procedure (which takes no parameters). In that procedure I check rows, if the fetched row is the same as previous (I determine that using one variable), if record in some column is equal, then omit this row, else insert into my table. That is all it does. And the procedure runs forever... Can anyone tell me why it takes so long?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Questions like this is almost always product specific.

Comment: I use Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2012 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a performance problem, and as such you need to investigate it as a performance problem. Please read [How to analyse SQL Server performance](http://rusanu.com/2014/02/24/how-to-analyse-sql-server-performance/).

Now, you are comparing a SELECT with a stored procedure **that does INSERT for one or more rows in that SELECT**. To expect them to be similar time is naive, at best. You are comparing **reads** with **writes**. Think: reads come from cache, writes go to disk.

You did not post any performance investigation data, so I'll use my magic 8-ball roll, which tells me you are issuing each INSERT in a standalone transaction and thus waiting for commit to flush for every INSERT. You cannot expect more than ~100 commits (rows) per second like this. You need to batch commit. Or, if on SQL Server 2014 or later, use [delayed durability](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn449490.aspx).

Shnugo also gives good advice, is (almost) always better to use one set operation instead of a cursor, when possible.

Answer (score 1):

I assume, that the insert operations on the table and your query, which you are calling over and over and the cursor, which relys on a given state of the table (indexes change on inserts!) are blocking each other.

The whole approach smells...

Do not use a `CURSOR` if you can avoid it! SQL is a set-based language and `CURSOR`s represent a procedural concept. Sometimes a `CURSOR` can be the right choice, but much more often one should solve a problem differently.

On the first sight [the `MERGE` statement might be perfect for you](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx)...

### UPDATE

One idea might be, to use a temp table variable to collect all needed data in a staging table and do the real inserts in one go at the end.

Comment: Is not possible for INSERT and cursor to block each other. It would be, by definition, a self-deadlock.

Comment: @RemusRusanu And what about the additional query *within* the `CURSOR`? As far as I understand this, the OP queries data in each turn to check, whether to manipulate or not...

Comment: It doesn't matter, any sort of data manipulation or querying would occur from the *same* connection. If blocking occurs, is a self deadlock.

Comment: @RemusRusanu Okay, that's pretty obvious actually :-) Thx for your insight!

Comment: Note: There's a word in the first paragraph that's unclear - "relys". Relies or on the off chance, Relays? I had edited out commentary but kept the word unchanged